# Javascript aliases

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

my goal is to create a sort of "Javascript library," if you could call it that.  I'm intending to use it to just manipulate pages as I browse the web, dynamically loading it as a greasemonkey script.  The idea is to have "`win`" get mapped to `window`, "`doc`" -> `document`, "`win.loc`" -> `win.location`, and a few other convenience mappings, but you get the idea.  Can you just give me a few examples for me to pick up the syntax from, and I'll extrapolate the rest?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just assign variables like so:

```
var win = window;
var doc = document;
```

You can't assign `win.loc` without modifying the `window` object in this case though. Also, the window object is special because after assigning `win`, you'll be able to get it with `win.win` or `win.win.win` and so on (`window` is the global object.)

In any case, you *can* still assign `loc` to the `window` object:

```
win.loc = window.location;

// Can now be referenced as:
loc; // (window is the global object)
win.loc;
win.location;
window.location;
```

Now that is how to do what you're asking for. Most likely you *shouldn't* do this. Normally, frameworks are defined to use up only one global variable, with a suitable name:

```
var Blixt = (function () {
    var localVariable = 123;

    return {
        loc: window.location,
        myFunc: function () {
            alert(localVariable);
        }
    };
})();
```

All this is pretty complex stuff if you're not familiar with JavaScript though, so it's not a good project to start with if you're new to JavaScript.

Comment: @Blixt Please see [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045889/javascript-aliases/1046094#1046094) to this question below, as what I would like to ask you about yours is too long for a comment. :) THanks!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**This is really a request for clarification of Blixt's answer above, which would not fit into one comment.

Ok, thanks - this is a pretty good answer. I'd just like to make some clarifications to it:

- If I define the aliases using the syntax you've given above, `win.loc` will behave *exactly* the same as `window.location` without any exceptions? (Just making sure)
- I followed most of it, but the part with the `Blixt` function I did not understand.  What is the expected behavior/result of defining this function?
- I *am* *kinda* new to JS, but why is this not a good idea?  What negative consequences could it possibly have?  I'm just looking to do things like `C-l javascript:win.loc=doc.ref<ENTER>` for a tab that was opened by CTRL-clicking a link in another tab, nothing too complex.
- Speaking of which, and I have a feeling that this might be different from browser to browser, but is there any possible way for me define a `js:` URI scheme  and map it to the `javascript:` one?  Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: (1) Yes, it's a reference to exactly the same object. (2) Blixt isn't a function; it's an object returned by the anonymous function (note that the function is called and Blixt is assigned to the result.) It's a technique usually called "closures" which means variables defined in the function are kept there rather than being defined in the global namespace. (3) If you're only keeping this script for yourself, it doesn't matter. But when mixing frameworks, you want to avoid affecting other frameworks as much as possible. (4) Nope, not possible I'm afraid.